# What are the stages of tomato splitting?

Tags: tomatoes

We all know tomatoes split, but what are the different stages of them splitting? can they heal from the various stages?

Comment: Do we know it? What do you mean for split? Not all varieties (maybe most of them) do not split. Non optimal watering increases the splits.

Comment: Tomato split is caused by irregular watering.... if the tomato dries out too much when fruit is present, and then is watered, the fruit grows rapidly, the skin can't keep up and it splits. Keep your watering regular and sufficient, especially once fruit starts growing. Splits do not repair themselves, though they may 'scab' over, but splits may cause fungal or bacterial organisms to enter the fruits.

Comment: i'm thinking big zac to mushroom basket

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Tomatoes splitting can be a natural, normal occurrence for many cultivars (especially big beefsteak type heirlooms). As far as stages go, I'd say there aren't really specially labelled stages of splitting, but the splits usually start before the fruit is ripe, and callous over sealing out rot before the fruit ripens.

The splitting will not reverse under any circumstances.